# Drupal Zen sub theme

Tags: drupal

New to php and drupal. I set up drupal and trying to customize the zen theme. Also setup Netbeans for debuggin. Everything is fine, but the menu variables are not filled as expected.

In page.tpl.php, there is a condition, `<?php if ($primary_links || $navigation): ?>` , which prints main menu if evaluates true. I get primary_links empty, so the menu doesn't print. According to the css provided by the zen theme, below ids should be used for customization.

```
/*
 * Primary and Secondary menu links
 */
#main-menu {
}

#secondary-menu {
}
```

I may add style elements looking through firebug, but the above id may be the right place to do it. So, why primary link variable is empty for me?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing that comes to mind is that, maybe, you haven't assigned anything to the primary links list. Have you?

Comment: yes.. indeed there was some links in the primary links as I could print those links in other areas.. In admin/build/blocks, when i place the primary links to Navigation bar, the navigation variable has some content.. but, primary_links (above expresssion) is still empty, so the message boady I needed is not printing..

Comment: thanks for the tip.. I did a fresh installation and it worked fine there.. by comparing, i saw "Source for the primary links: " is disabled in my settings.. i was following few tutorials and trying out different settings.. thanks again..